# What is the correct JavaScript data structure to store lease type, lease term, lease range to get the proper lease rate?

Tags: javascript

I have a leasing company, lease price, lease type, a lease term, a lease start range, and a lease end range, that all compute to a lease rate.  I am just not sure exactly what type of data structure to use to easily store and look up this information.

I have a UI that has the dropdowns for leasing company, lease type, lease term, and a textbox for the lease price.  So, those are the inputs.  I really don't know how to store the data so it is easy to lookup.  So, given the lease type and the lease term, I would have a set of ranges and when the lease price falls in that range then a lease rate would be selected.  The end result is

```
Leasing Company:
<select id="leasing-company"></select>
<br/>

Lease Type:
<select id="lease-type"></select>
<br/>

Lease Term:
<select id="lease-term"></select>
<br/>

// the way I am storing the data to feed to the select options
var dict1 = {
    leasing_company: "XYZ Leasing Company",
    lease_type: ["fmv", "buyout"],
    lease_term: [12, 24, 36, 39, 48]
};

// some example values
var leaseType = ["fmv", "buyout"]
var leaseTerm = [12, 24, 36, 39, 48]
var leaseRanges = [0.00, 1500.00, 3000.00, 5000.00, 10000.00]
var leaseRates = [0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.10, 0.05]
```

Everything I have tried requires quite a bit of looping.  I figure there has to be a better way to look up the data from the dropdowns.

Leasing Company --> Lease Type --> Lease Term --> find Lease Range --> output Lease Rate

Comment: So each rate is tied to one range, but how are the ranges associated to the terms and types? Or are they not associated at all?

Comment: Can you show us the "quite a bit of looping" code you'd use to get the desired results? I'm still not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but if we have a working example we can suggest improvements to the data structures.

Comment: Ugh. I am embarrassed to say that I don't have a working example. I am stuck on how to approach this problem.  Each lease type has a list of lease terms, each lease term has a list of ranges, the range then has a rate associated with it.

Comment: Then go with a tree structure that represents exactly that: `leases = [{type:"…", terms:[{term:"…",ranges:[{range:…, rate:…}, …]}, …]}, …]`. If you want less looping and more lookup, use types and terms as keys of an object: `{"typeA": {"term1": […], "term2": …}, …}`.

Comment: Bet.  That seems like a good approach.  Let me see if I can get it worked out.  Thanks @Bergi!  I appreciate your timely responses.

Comment: @Bergi I figured out a solution that makes the database do the work.  For now, I am going to pass the company, type, term, and price to the database and do a select statement to find the range.

Comment: Ah, letting the database figure out the most efficient index structure is the simplest solution :-) Requires an ajax call for each input though if you want interactive results.

Comment: @Bergi that's the rub.  An ajax call each time the drop downs are changed.  Oh well, technical debt, right?  When I get the chance, I want to tackle doing the calculation on the client-side.  Right now pressed for time. :)